# why cannot i see any error in intelliJ logcat view?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, logcat, android-logcat

I write android app (gradle based) in intellij 14 IDEA.

My app crashes in debug, but I cannot see in the logcat any stacktrace or error log.

how can it be? (my app, verbose level)

[image]

when I change to (no filter, verbose level) I see the bug:

[image]

Comment: Your device seems to be tagging the crash log as AndroidRuntime.  Not much you can do t fix that, you'll have to turn off filtering or add it to your filter to see it.

Comment: but when I used eclipse it was filtering OK other app I was writing. what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

u must find something like Perspective (which is top of page -> on right,in Eclipse location and we call it Perspective in Eclipse) and change it from DDMS or something like that to java.
and java will be your Default Perspective
after that you will see also logcat.